# TortoiseSVN client pre commit hook to check the contents of file being committed

Tags: svn, batch-file, tortoisesvn, pre-commit-hook

I want to write a pre commit hook in windows batch file which will check for specific string in the file being committed. If the string exists, the commit will fail. I have TortoiseSVN client installed. As it's tortoisesvn client, it does not have commands like 'svnlook' to fetch the list of files etc. I want that script to be executed for each and every file being committed/added.

I am newbie to these hooks. Can anyone please guide me with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be this page will be helpful

1. [Client Side Hook Scripts](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks)
2. [TortoiseSVN pre-commit hook in C# - Save yourself some troubles!](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528302/TortoiseSVN-pre-commit-hook-in-Csharp-Save-yoursel)

Seems like you can use FIND batch command, because it produces errorcode when string in file is not found.